# Missing ssd storage space

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk-cloning

I cloned my old HDD to a new HDD. My old HDD was 149GB with 6.8GB free space. The new HDD is 750GB. As you can see the new drive is much bigger than the old HDD.

After the cloning was done I noticed that the new drive only shows up as 149GB, with 6.8GB free space. (Same as the old drive).  I know there should be at least 500 GB still free on the new drive.

My question are:

- Where is it.
- Can I redo or format the new drive to remove this information.
- What software would be best to use? (I used Emselus home ed. to clone.)

Comment: If you put a glass (your 149gb old image) in a bucket (your 750gb drive), the glass still holds the same amount (149gb).

Answer (score 3):

If you made a whole disk image of the old HDD then that included the boot sector and the partitioning. Restoring that image on a larger drive will not result in more available space.

Think of it as making a copy of a book.

The original book is 150 pages long and has an index which describes pages 1 to 150.
The new book is 750 pages long. You copied the content, including the index which describes that 150 pages are available.

If you want to use the rest of the space you will have to change the index. (Or in HDD term, the partitioning).

Answer (score 0):

When you clone the drives the partitions don't change. The remaining space on the drive is not assigned to a partition. Use a partitioning tool e.g. [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net) to increase the size of your partition.